# Can't start/debug application in VS2013 anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Since today I can't debug any applications anymore.
If I want to start the debug session, I get the error message

> error while trying to run application: invalid pointer

It doesn't depends on the project, this behaviour appears in every project/solution.

What i've already tried:

- Reset VS settings
- repair Visual Studio
- complete reinstall of visual studio
- Changed Build Platform to x86/x64
- Enabled native code debugging

Comment: http://aliiraza.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/visual-studio-2012-rc-error-while-trying-to-run-project-invalid-pointer/

Comment: as you can see, i already tried that

Answer (score 1):

If you press Ctrl-F5 to run the application, you won't get the error and the application will start, but you can't do debug, so this isn't a real solution.
The only way to solve the problem is to update Visual Studio: I had the same problem (WPF application), which was solved by the Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running VS 2013 and get an error that's pointing to the body tag, try adding this to the web.config under

```
<appSettings>

<add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled" />
```

That key disables browser link which currently isn't playing nice.

Comment: i forgot to mention that it has to do with c# projects.